# VLC - Why is audio track longer than video track after a screencasting?

Tags: linux, audio, video, vlc-media-player, lag

I use VLC media player 2.2.8 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.7-14-g3cc1d8cba9), installed from my distrib repo (Arch Linux). My purpose is to create a command which records a video of my desktop, with audio input from micro.

After some research, I've used this command :

```
vlc screen:// 
:screen-fps=24 
:screen-follow-mouse 
:screen-mouse-image=cursor.png 
:input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0
:sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264,vb=2048,acodec=mp3,scale=1.0,vfilter=croppadd{cropleft=0,croptop=0,cropright=0,cropbottom=0}}:duplicate{dst=std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=out.mp4}}"
```

I tested it for a ~1mn video, and it worked without any noticeable issue.
Then I recorded an ~1h video, and the result is the following :
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7W7q.png) (imgur).

The values are approximative. The audio lag begins with ~3s, and finishes with ~3mn. Except the lag, video and audio work properly.

Why is there an audio lag ?
Is it due to some sort of compression, or some reasons like "the micro input is slower than screen video capture" ?

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have found a solution. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

## Solution

```
vlc screen:// 
:screen-fps=24 

...

:sout="#transcode{...fps=24}...
```

The solution is to specify the same fps in the transcode option than in the :screen-fps option.

Complete command (for reference) :

```
vlc screen:// 
:screen-fps=24 
:screen-follow-mouse 
:screen-mouse-image=cursor.png 
:input-slave=alsa://hw:1,0
:sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264,vb=2048,acodec=mp3,scale=1.0,vfilter=croppadd{cropleft=0,croptop=0,cropright=0,cropbottom=0},fps=24}:duplicate{dst=std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=out.mp4}}"
```

---

## Details

By default, VLC has :

- an input of `500 000 µs`,
- an output of `40 000 µs`.

You can see it in the console after the vlc command :
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EhqJ.png) (imgur).

- The `:screen-fps=24` option provides the `stream_out_transcode stream out: input interval 41666 (base 1)` option to VLC.
- The `fps=24` in `transcode` option provides the `stream_out_transcode stream out: output interval 41666 (base 1)` option to VLC.

If I am right, to obtain `41666` from `24` fps (or Hz), we need to do the following operation :
`10^6 / 24 = 41666.66666... ~= 41666 µs`

In my original post, I did not define `fps=24` in the `transcode` option. So, the default value for output interval was `40 000` µs.

If I consider my video is `3600` s long, and I do the following operation :
`3600 * (1-40000/41666) = 143.9447` seconds.

It is > 2mn, and it corresponds with the observed delta.

Result with correct options : [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Grd.png) (imgur).

---

## Remark

Although it exists a parameter `audio-sync` in `transcode` option, it didn't work as I expected. Only adding `fps` parameter did the trick.

---

## References

You can find references here :

- [:screen-fps](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/screen/)
- [fps in transcode](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Advanced_Streaming_Using_the_Command_Line/#fps)
- [audio-sync in transcode](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Advanced_Streaming_Using_the_Command_Line/#audio-sync)